# How to fix this code while using dynamic 2D array

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm using dynamic 2D array and need the value of particular index but it is not printing the correct value.

````
```int u=5;//No. of elements
int S[u];
int i=0;
while(i<u)//elements in universal set
{
    cin>>S[i];
    i++;
}
int n;
cin>>n;//no. of subset
i=0;
int subcost[n];
int **subset;
subset=new int*[n];
while(i<n)
{
    int l,c;
    cin>>l;//size of ith subset
    subset[i]=new int[l];
    int j=0;
    while(j<l)//Elements in each subset
    {
        cin>>subset[i][j];
        j++;
    }
    cin>>c;//cost for each subset
    subcost[i]=c;
    i++;
}

i=0;
while(i<n)
{
    int j=0;
    int s=*subset[i];
    while(j<s)
    {
        cout<<subset[i][j]<<"\n";
        j++;
    }
    i++;
}```
````

I expect the output to be value of each subset, but the actual output is totally different.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to go through the [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) on what and how you can ask here.It's specially important to post a [mcve].

Comment: What is the *real* problem you try to solve here? Why do you think you need a "2D array"? Especially since it seems you only want an array of integers?

Comment: Also, unless this is an exercise or school assignment, in just about all cases where you think "dynamic array" you next thought should *always* be `std::vector`.

Comment: I am trying to solve approximate set cover problem where user will give number of subset they want to have and each subset will have their own elements that's i needed a 2D array

Comment: If you have an array of pointers (which is really the closes approximation to what `arr` is), then why did you expect `arr[i]` to be a value? You allocate memory for an array of `int`, so you need to read the values into `arr[i][j]`.

Comment: You want to print the values of a 2D array, but at no point in your code do you give your 2D array any values. In any case if you want a value from a 2D array its `a[i][j]` not `a[i]`. A 2D array means you have to provide **two** indexes.

Comment: `int S[u];` C++ does not allow *Variable Length Arrays*. You must declare the array using a literal integer constant or declare a pointer and dynamically allocate storage with `new`, or use a container like `vector` (or in your 2D case a `vector<vector int>`) Show 10 lines of input.

Comment: Do note that major edits to your question could make existing comments and answer totally inaccurate (which have happened here). Instead of doing that, delete the question and post a new one with the correct information and code from the beginning.  And please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Describing the output as "totally different" is almost totally unhelpful. Better would be to list the input, the expected output, and the actual output.

Answer (score 0):

```
arr[i]=new int[n1];
```

There's a misunderstanding of what `new` does. (Perhaps you come from Java?) This doesn't store an integer with the value of `n1`. It instead creates an array with a size of `n1`.

Just one pointer level should be enough for an array:

```
int n = 5;
int i = 0;

int *arr;
arr = new int[n];
arr[i] = 100;

cout << arr[i] << endl;  // output: 100


delete[] arr;  // remember to deallocate – otherwise memory leaks will haunt your system!
```

If you're looking for a 2D array, a pointer to a pointer (`**`) will work.

```
int **arr;
arr = new int[n];       //
arr[0] = new int[n];    //  allocate first array
arr[0][0] = 100;        //  set first element of first array

delete[] arr[0];
delete[] arr;           //  deallocate
```

Comment: Thanks a lot but currently i'm solving approximate set cover problem where i need 2D array where number of subset will be given by the user, here i am including the code`.cout<<"Subset elements are :- "<<"\n";
    while(i<n)
    {
        int j=0;
        int s=*subset[i];
        cout<<"Size of Subset "<<i<<" is:- "<<s<<"\n";
        cout<<"Subset "<<i<<"th elements are :- "<<"\n";
        while(j<s)
        {
            cout<<subset[i][j]<<"\n";
            j++;
        }
        cout<<"cost = "<<subcost[i]<<"\n\n\n\n\n\n";
        i++;
    } `here i am not getting the correct

Comment: I have already done this, but yet i am getting a wrong output.```int **subset;
    subset=new int*[n];
    while(i<n)
    {
        int l,c;
        cout<<"Please Enter the size of subset "<<i<<"\n";
        cin>>l;
        subset[i]=new int[l];
        int j=0;
        cout<<"Please Enter the elements in the list"<<"\n";
        while(j<l)
        {
            cin>>subset[i][j];
            j++;
        }}```

Comment: @NileshKumar Post any code you have in the question, not in comments (you really should have done that from the start).

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
arr[i]=new int[n1]; /* allocating memory for arr[i], equal to n1*sizeof(int) bytes & arr[i] gets points to address returned by new */
cout<<"Value of "<<i<<"th row is :- "<<arr[i]<<"\n";
```

> I expect the output to be value of n1, but the actual output is **some
>   random address** ?

yes, `arr[i]` is dynamically created array & printing it will prints its base address only.

Try this version where I tried to explain code changes in comments.

```
int main(void) {
    std::cout<<"Enter the value of n"<<"\n";
    int n;
    std::cin>>n;
    int **arr;
    /* allocate memory for arr. arr holds base address of array of n int ptr */
    arr=new int*[n];
    int i=0;
    int n1;
    std::cout<<"Enter the value of n1"<<"\n";
    std::cin>>n1;
    /* allocate memory for arr[0], arr[1] .. */
    while(i < n1) {
        arr[i]=new int[n1];
        i++;
    }
    /* put the data into dynamically allocated array */
    for(int row = 0; row < n; row++) {
        for(int col = 0; col < n1; col++) {
            std::cin>>arr[row][col];
        }
    }
    /* printh te data */
    for(int row = 0; row < n; row++) {
        for(int col = 0; col < n1; col++) {
            std::cout<<"Value of "<<i<<"th row is :- "<<arr[row][col];
        }
        std::cout<<"\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And since you created dynamic array using `new` you need to free the dynamically allocated memory to avoid memory leakage, use `delete` operator accordingly.

As pointed by others `std::vector` is better option than above one.

Answer (score 0):

While you have a good answer from @Achal for dynamically allocating, as mentioned, you really should use the container `vector` provided by C++ to make things much easier and more robust. All C++ containers provided automatic memory management freeing you from having to allocate manually (and with much less chance of getting it wrong)

When using containers, such as a vector of vectors to store your data, you can simply read and discard your `"//elements in universal set"`, `"//no. of subset"` and `"//Elements in each subset"`. Those values are not required when using containers. You simply read the value you want and add it to your container, the container will grow as needed to accommodate.

While it is not 100% clear what your input data looks like, we can deduce from your file it looks something like:

**Example Input File**

Where your first integers is your `"//elements in universal set"` which isn't needed to read the data. Likewise the second line, your `"//no. of subset"` is irrelevant for reading the data. Finally the 1st element on each data row, your `"//Elements in each subset"` is also not needed. Each of these values is simply read and discarded to arrive at your final data set.

```
$ cat dat/universal_sub.txt
5
4
5 1 2 3 4 5
3 1 2 3
4 1 2 3 4
6 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

**The Final Dataset You Want To Store**

From the full file, these appear to be the actual data values you want to store (there can be an even number, but there is no requirement for that)

```
1 2 3 4 5
1 2 3
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4 5 6
```

There are many different ways you can put the pieces together. A short example of how to get your final dataset from your input file could be:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <limits>

int main (void) {

    std::string line;                       /* string for reading each line */
    std::vector<std::vector <int>> subset;  /* vector<vector<int>> */
    int universal, nsubsets;                /* two int to read/discard */

    if (!(std::cin >> universal >> nsubsets)) { /* read/dicard 2 values */
        std::cerr << "error: failed to read universal.\n";
        return 1;
    }
    /* read/discard '\n' (any chars) left in input buffer line by cin above */
    std::cin.ignore (std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');

    while (getline (std::cin, line)) {  /* read each remaining data line */
        int unneeded, i;                /* 1st value and i for rest */
        std::vector<int> tmp;           /* vector<int> for each line */
        std::stringstream ss (line);    /* stringstream to read from */
        if (ss >> unneeded) {           /* read/discard 1st value */
            while (ss >> i)             /* read rest from stringstream */
                tmp.push_back(i);       /* add to tmp vector */
            subset.push_back(tmp);      /* add tmp vector to subset */
        }
    }

    for (auto& i : subset) {        /* loop over subsets */
        for (auto& j : i)           /* loop over each value in subset */
            std::cout << " " << j;  /* output value */
        std::cout << '\n';          /* tidy up with newline */
    }
}
```

(**note:** the output loops make use of the [Range-based for loop (since C++11)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) but you are free to use the `.begin()` and `.end()` container functions with a traditional `for` loop if your compile does not support `std=c++11`)

**Exaple Use/Output**

Reading your data into a vector of vectors allows accessing each element:

```
$ ./bin/vector_2d_subset < dat/universal_sub.txt
 1 2 3 4 5
 1 2 3
 1 2 3 4
 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions or if I interpreted your data file format incorrectly.